# Image proxy REGEX in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Using PHP.

I have an html document on a variable, I want to look inside this code for all instances of the img tag, and prepend some text to its src attribute, I want to avoid using client side code like javascript and let php handle all the heavy lifting, I was thinking of using regular expressions to do this, like find all instances of `<img [ ]* src="` , Im not very savy on regex as you can see, how can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: And what do you want from SO users?

Comment: Don't use regexp to process HTML, use a DOM parsing library like Simple PHP DOM Parser.

Comment: [Probably not a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2370483)

Comment: Use a DOM parser, not a regex for this task.

Comment: I cant use a DOM parser, have to do it through regex. its how it was required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will match all img tags and capture the contents inside `src` which then you can use to replace with something prepended to it.

```
/\<img.+src="(.+)".*\/\>/
```

You can see how it's working here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3Mk

Answer (score 0):

Use a DOM parser, they're simple and so much less error prone.

That said, it's Friday, and if this was a one off fix to correct some broken URLs (say the image directory got moved up a level) in a few HTML files, I'd be whipping out Notepad++ and doing a quick regex find and replace.

```
/(<img[^>]*src=")/i
```

Replacing with `\1whatever`:

```
preg_replace('/(<[^>]*src=")/i', '\1whatever', $subject);
```